# Does this property of a partially ordered set have a name?

Tags: set-theory, posets, reference-request, terminology

What do you call a poset with this property? For any elements $a,b,c,d$ such that $\{a,b\}\le\{c,d\}$, there is an element x such that $\{a,b\}\le x\le\{c,d\}$. (Equivalently, for any finite sets $A\le B$, there is an element x such that $A\le x\le B$.)

For example, any upper or lower semilattice has this property. Also, overlooking the fact that it's not a set, the class of all cardinal numbers has this property in ZF.

Comment: Trees also have this property.

Comment: That´s sometimes called a well-joined (well-met for the dual notion) partial order.

Comment: In analogy with the LUB property, you could call it the DUB property (directed upper bound property), since you are saying that every bounded-above finite set has a directed collection of upper bounds (and similarly for lower bounds).

Comment: What does it mean that $\lbrace a,b\rbrace\leq\lbrace c,d\rbrace$? Both $a$ and $b$ are smaller than both $c$ and $d$?

Comment: I think a better name would be the "Ham Sandwich Property" or the "Bacon Cheeseburger Property".

Comment: @ramiro: I think that a forcing notion is called "well-met" if any two conditions with a common lower bound have a greatest lower bound. This is slightly stronger than "DUB". http://www.jstor.org/stable/2274204

Comment: @Goldstern: Thats's right, my comment about well-met posets was answering a question made by Butch in another comment not the original question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: For the last example in the post, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130768/cardinals-without-choice-interpolation-reference-wanted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the world of partially ordered abelian groups, this is the *interpolation property*.
These groups are called *partially ordered abelian groups with interpolation*, or simply *interpolation groups*. Intuitively, I think about them as "almost as nice as lattice ordered abelian groups".

A simple example of a non-lattice ordered interpolation group is the set of all
polynomial functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Probably the most important subclass is the class of *dimension groups*. As proved by Effros, Handelman and Shen [in 1980](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2374244?uid=3739024&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102296591717), dimension groups classify
the [approximate finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximately_finite_dimensional_C%2A-algebra) (via the $K_0$ functor).

I recommend this [book by Goodearl](http://books.google.sk/books/about/Partially_Ordered_Abelian_Groups_With_In.html?id=dXUsGysPqRUC&redir_esc=y) -- very readable, he is an excellent writer.